# Invoke-Command write file to parent machine

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a script that connects to a remote machine using `Invoke-Command` and then runs a script block. This all works fine, however I would like to know if its possible to write a log file on to the parent machine. Due to firewalling on the servers the parent can connect to the child, but the child cannot connect to the parent.

At the moment when I use `Out-File` it creates that file on the server that I am connected to. I would like to find a way to create that file, and append to it on the server that I am connecting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output in the scriptblock is returned to the caller. Simply pipe or redirect the output of `Invoke-Command` to a file.

```
Invoke-Command -Computer ... -ScriptBlock {...} > 'C:\path\to\out.txt'
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -Computer ... -ScriptBlock {...} | Out-File 'C:\path\to\out.txt'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it wrote to an empty file. What I used was:
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock{Write-Host "This is from the server"} | Out-File $logFile`

Comment: Sorted, I needed to use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`

Comment: [Explanation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/).